# Minecraft Server Wasn't Auto-Saving, Save Data Gone. Any Hope to Get it Back?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Recently, I closed my Minecraft server the same way I always have--clicking the red x to close the window. For whatever reason, it's stopped saving over the last ten days. When I reopened the server, none of the data from the last ten days was there. None of the new buildings, none of the items, etc etc.

When looking at the files, the latest backup for anything--world, player, etc data--is also ten days ago. I'm aware that, unless somehow the data has been saving to the wrong folder, it's never been saved to at all.

My question is if there's anything to be done. Is all of the memory simply held in RAM while the console is running the server? We've had players log in and log out plenty of times, but all of their information was fine. It's hard to believe that that console running was managing everything.

I've recovered """permanently deleted""" Data before from some hardware. I'm willing to pull my computer apart for that too.

Comment: Minecraft constantly writes chunks and stuff to the hard drive, it doesn't just keep everything in RAM. Are you sure you started the server with the same folder again? Try searching for folders called "region" on your entire hard drive(s?), maybe you were playing in the backup folder instead or somewhere else entirely.

Comment: You may also want to look into the reason why it stopped saving automatically. Just so it doesn't happen again! (Pretty obvious, I know, just covering all bases!)